# Can different DB connections update the same transaction in Oracle?

Tags: c#, oracle, asp.net-web-api, transactions

I think I know the answer to this, but it's worth a shot...

I have a big chunk of plsql.  It's all wrapped in one transaction.  I'd like to migrate a portion of it to an internal web service (mvc .net / entity).

But of course the transaction isn't committed so the service can't update the records it would like to.

It sure would be great if the plsql that calls the service could pass the transaction, transaction name, context, connection, something to the service and the service could return it for further changes.

And actually, the transaction begins in .net/wpf, goes to plsql and returns and commits in wfp.  So the idea would be to start a transaction in wpf, go to plsql, which calls a service, returns to plsql and then to wpf and commit.  We could break the plsql into two pieces so .net could call the plsql, the service and then resume the transaction in plsql and commit later in .net.

Comment: Take a look at [`DBMS_XA`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_xa.htm#ARPLS209).  I've never used it, but according to the documentation "Using this package, application developers can switch or share transactions across SQL*Plus sessions or processes using PL/SQL."

Comment: Thanks - our DBA looked at me skeptically, but it appears to be a possible solution.  If we end up padding the suspended session around from plsql to .net and back, I'll follow up.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement but I was updating multiple databases and needed one transaction to commit or rollback everything as appropriate.  I ended up using the `System.Transactions` namespace and created a `TransactionScope`.  I had to install a component from my Oracle driver but am pretty sure that was all that was needed.  This would allow you to control the transaction from your WPF solution and call whatever is required.

There is no "Rollback" statement, not calling the `Complete()` method will naturally rollback the transaction at the end of the using statement.

```
using (var trans = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
{
    var cn  = new OracleConnection();
    // perform PL/SQL

    if (success())
    {
        // this is the "Commit"
        trans.Complete();
    }
}
```

See [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.transactions.transactionscope?view=netframework-4.8) for further details.